# How should I control the access to image in tomcat?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, accessibility

We have a web application written in java, there is a folder which contains many images, user can access those images using:
http://localhost:8080/test/images/a.jpg
I am thinking how can I control the images, and enable only authorized user can view those images ?
Please point me the right direction, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your web application is deployed under context "/test". You can implement a ServletFilter, and configure it to be executed for *.jpg (and any other image format pattern). Inside the ServletFilter, you can test for authorization.

Please see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) link for more information on Servlet Filters. 
If you are using the latest Servlet 3.0 implementation, you can refer to [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) link.

Answer (score 1):

There is the standard [Java EE declarative security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html) you can define in web.xml.  If you don't need fine-grained control over which users access which images, this might do and is fairly easy to configure.  If you are using Tomcat, you also need to [configure a security realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html).  This option will work well if, for example, users should be able to access all images or none at all.

This won't be a good option if you need fine-grained control over security, such as if each individual user has different access rights to different images.